# Copy the results from ADODB query to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Do you know please how to copy all results from my query (about 360 observations) to sheet test, starting in A1 ? My code is :

```
Public Sub cible_2()

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
RECSET.Open "select  (tiers.S_RAISONSOC||'-'||k.CD_TIERS) as cible from db_protocole proto, db_tiers tiers, db_personne pers" & _
            " where s_raisonsoc not like '%NE PLUS UTILISER %'  and proto.is_tiers =tiers.is_tiers and pers.is_personne =tiers.is_personne ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
If Not RECSET.EOF Then
    Worksheets("test").Range("A1").Value = RECSET.Fields("cible").Value
Else
    Worksheets("test").Range("A1").Value = "test"
End If
RECSET.Close
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for you help !
Best regards,
Marie

Comment: `Worksheets("test").Range("A1").copyfromrecordset recset` should be enough.

Comment: @Roy, thank you very much. Unfortunately, my condition: where pers.S_RAISONSOC not like '*NE PLUS UTILISER*' doesn't work, maybe you see the error in my code ? I don't want to have the values starting by NE PLUS UTILISER.

Comment: Add a `%` wildcard character to the end of your `NOT LIKE` criteria string. Without the wildcards it's an exact match.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, thank you, that works ! :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, do you know please some site that expalains how to create the ComboBox with the result of my query. I'm completely beginner on this subject. Thank you very much !  Marie

Comment: You can either iterate the recordset and invoke `AddItem` at each record to manually populate the control, or you can use `Range.CopyFromRecordset` to dump all records to a particular range of cells; assuming it's an ActiveX combobox once the records are in the worksheet you can just set the control's `ListFillRange` to that range, and done - no need for any loops.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thank you very much, do you have some link to the site where is some explaination about it please, it's still very abstract for me :)